# Python requests giving error ('Connection aborted.', error("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",)) when attempting to post to gfycat.com

Tags: python, http, https, python-requests, gfycat

I am executing the code:

```
import requests

clientID = redacted
secret =redacted

filename = "temp2.gif"
datakey = '{ "title":"random title"}'

r = requests.post("https://api.gfycat.com/v1/gfycats", data = datakey)
gfyname = r.json()["gfyname"]
print(r.json())
print(gfyname)

params_ = {'client_id': clientID, 'client_secret': secret, 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

r = requests.post('https://api.gfycat.com/v1/oauth/token', data=str(params_))

access_token = r.json()['access_token']

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
print(headers)
data = {'key': gfyname}
url = "https://filedrop.gfycat.com"
files = {gfyname: open(filename, 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
print(r)
```

It all executes fine until the very last request.post() call which is when I receive the error message:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))`

I have verified the requests endpoints/params with the gfycat api documentation. I have checked the output of the `headers` and the `access_token`. I have read through the requests documentation and I did find a few things to which I fixed. and now I am stuck here, trying to figure out why the connection is aborting.

Comment: Are those `https` sites, self singed ?

Comment: This is not the correct answer but try using `verify=False` in your post request, if it worked, let me know.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar I do not know to be honest. 
I tried verify=False and it still gave same error. I am able to get all the way to the last requests.post call before it fails so the rest of the posts work fine.

Comment: what about this :
`r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=open(filename, 'rb'), headers=headers)`

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar if I run that code exactly, I get the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` and if I run `r = requests.post(url, data=data, files0={gfyname: open(filename, 'rb')}, headers=headers)` instead, I get the original error.

Answer (score -1):

use [pfycat](https://pypi.org/project/pfycat/)

```
import pfycat
c = pfycat.Client("client_id", "client_secret")
r = c.upload('banana.gif')
print(r)
```

---

alternatively: look how [pfycat does it](https://gitlab.com/juergens/pfycat/blob/master/pfycat/__init__.py)